# How to get color name from integer value in c#?

Tags: c#, colors

How do I get color name from an integer value saved in database. For example when I save Black color it saves as "-16777216" and when I convert this integer value back to color I get color name as "ff000000" instead of "Black".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well what have you tried so far? Presumably you should be performing a SQL query against the integer...

Comment: I'm assuming this is WinForms?

Comment: Yes this is windows forms but I'm using DevExpress ColorEdit control.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
private System.Drawing.Color GetSystemDrawingColorFromHexString(string hexString)
{
    if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(hexString, @"[#]([0-9]|[a-f]|[A-F]){6}\b"))
        throw new ArgumentException();
    int red = int.Parse(hexString.Substring(1, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    int green = int.Parse(hexString.Substring(3, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    int blue = int.Parse(hexString.Substring(5, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    return Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);
}

Color color = GetSystemDrawingColorFromHexString(colorCode);
return color.GetKnownColor();
```

Comment: Did you meant `ToKnownColor`?

Comment: And what does `GetSystemDrawingColorFromHexString` do exactly? Because `Color.ToKnownColor` won't return the name of a color created using the `Color.FromArgb()` method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.toknowncolor(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: My apologizes. I miss the previous method. Try it again.

Comment: @MárcioGonzalez still won't work, read the link I provided, ToKnownColor will not give the name of a color created using FromArgb, even if it is a known color.